# Overflowing content shows with delay

Tags: jquery, css

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9mg6vjaf/3

```
<div id="nav-icon3">
<span>Menu</span>
</div>


     <div id="#sideMenu" class="navigationLeft">

        <div class="flag"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.navigationLeft {
    width: 385px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #191919;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9;
}

.flag {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;left:0;
   width:500px; height:100%;
   background-color: red;
   transform-origin:0 0;
   transform:skew(10deg);
   z-index:-1;
}
```

JS

```
    $('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('#nav-icon3').click(function() {
  $('.navigationLeft').slideToggle(400);
});
```

When I click on "Menu" I want the whole .navigationLeft slide in smoothly, but currently the overflowing content is showing with some delay. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The jquery method .slideToggle applies the css rule: overflow:hidden to the element while it animates. You can force an override of this by adding   overflow: visible !important; to your .navigationLeft class.

```
.navigationLeft {
    overflow: visible !important;
    /*... other css rules */
}
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9mg6vjaf/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `width` of `.navigationLeft` is smaller than the `width` of `.flag`. As such, as jQuery animates, it calculates to the width of `.navigationLeft`, then has to 'recalculate' for the flag width. In order to prevent this, you need to ensure that the container for the flag has enough width to cover when it fully expands.

Giving the navigation a larger width (in this case `100%`) fixes the problem:

```js
$('#nav-icon3').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});

$('#nav-icon3').click(function() {
  $('.navigationLeft').slideToggle(400);
});
```

```css
.navigationLeft {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #191919;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
}

.flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: skew(10deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-icon3">
  <span>Меню</span>
</div>
<div id="#sideMenu" class="navigationLeft">
  <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Actually, I don't want the whole page to be black. I will edit my jsfiddle so it's more clear.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. So now I want my .navigationLeft to look the way it look when you click on "menu", it's just that I want to get rid of the delay of the overflowing area.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap the section with another invisible wrapper without background then it will solve your purpose.

Without having a wrapper width that is greater than the skew it's not possible to do it.

```
    <div id="nav-icon3">
    <span>Меню</span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="#sideMenu" class="navigationLeft">


        </div>
        <div class="flag"></div>
     </div>


.navigationLeft {
  width:385px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #191919;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9;
}

.flag {
   position:absolute;
   top:50px;left:0;
   width:500px; height:100%;
   background-color: red;
   transform-origin:0 0;
   transform:skew(10deg);
   display: none;
   z-index: 10;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
#nav-icon3{
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/9mg6vjaf/4/